# How to prevent a given string from filtering

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of universities around the world. I want to filter by name.

```
[{
'web_pages': ['http://www.uopeople.edu/'],
 'name': 'University of the People', 
'alpha_two_code': 'US', 
'state-province': None, 
'domains': ['uopeople.edu'], 
'country': 'United States'
},...
]
```

I want to use stop words such as ['university', 'the', 'of'].
That way if someone tries to search by uni, univer, university, etc
No results should be returned.

Can I do this with a regex? Something simple should be good.

This is what I have for now:

```
output_dict = [x for x in self.schools_list if school.lower() in x['name'].lower() or  school.lower() in x['domains'][0].lower()]
```

Comment: It would be better for you to add a list of "match" words in each entry -- the words that should bring up this entry.  Then, your search task becomes easy.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts. I don't get this part " add a list of "match" words in each entry". Can you elaborate on that? thanks

Comment: What I mean is, add a list of the words that should lead people to this entry.  For your example, you might include "people", "usa", "united", "states", etc.

Comment: I get it. But won't that be an overkill?

Comment: As opposed to what?  It certainly makes the SEARCH code a lot simpler.  If you already had a plan for what to search, then maybe it would be too much trouble.